# SwiftData Query is not sorting as expected

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

I have a SwiftData model that has a timestamp property I want to sort based on the timestamp property.

```swift
@Model
public final class ExperienceContent {
    @Attribute(.unique)
    public let id: UUID

    public var details: AnyOf3<String, RawImage?, Data>
    public var experience: Experience?
    public var timestamp: Date
    public var subContent: String

    public init(
        id: UUID = UUID(),
        details: AnyOf3<String, RawImage?, Data>,
        timestamp: Date = .now,
        subContent: String = ""
    ) {
        self.id = id
        self.details = details
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.subContent = subContent
    }
}
```

I have `ExperienceContentView` that displays these contents

```swift
struct ExperienceContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Environment(Navigator.self) private var navigator

    private let experience: Experience

    @Query private var content: [ExperienceContent]

    init(experience: Experience) {
        self.experience = experience
        let experienceID = experience.id
        self._content = Query(
            FetchDescriptor<ExperienceContent>(
                predicate: #Predicate<ExperienceContent>{
                    $0.experience?.id == experienceID
                },
                sortBy: [
                    // I also tried using the order parameter
                    SortDescriptor(\ExperienceContent.timestamp)
                ]
            )
        )
    }

    var body: some View {
        List(experience.content) { content in
            Section(
                content: {
                    switch content.details {
                    case .a0(let text):
                        Text(text)
                    case .a1(var image):
                        EmptyView()
                    case .a2(_):
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                },
                header: {
                    Text("TODO")
                },
                footer: {
                    Text(content.subContent)
                }
            )
        }
        .toolbar {
            Menu {
               // menu buttons
            } label: {
                SFSymbol.plusAppFill.image
                    .font(.title)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

however, whenever i add a new record, the order does not seem to matter.
every time i create a new record I specify the current Date.now

I also checked the database and the time seems to align with the expectations.

[image]

however, when I get to the view it does not look like the contents are in the expected order.

[image]

I was wondering if anyone has any experience with this.

Comment: In my experience, `@Query` records seem to come in random order each time (at least, in memory-only "test" configurations). However, you can specify the query sort order. Here's a succinct tutorial for that: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftdata/sorting-query-results

Comment: What happens if you use a plain List without the Section (but with the sort descriptor)?